# Workaround for OS X Docker 'Directory renamed before its status could be extracted'

Tags: macos, docker, tar

Using Docker Desktop Community 2.0.0.3 on OS X 10.14.5, I've started up an ubuntu image and inside it am running the installer for some arm cross-compilers. This causes a host of errors like:

> tar: ./sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/etc: Directory
>   renamed before its status could be extracted

Some googling suggests that this is a common Docker bug, and that a workaround for this is to [change the storage driver](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19647), e.g. to aufs, but when I try this on a Mac, docker fails to start, with an error referencing graphdriver.  And indeed the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#docker-desktop-for-mac-and-docker-desktop-for-windows) suggests changing storage driver is not supported on Macs.

Has anyone found a way to workaround this tar error?

Comment: The page you linked to says that you _can_ change the storage driver in Mac to `vfs` as a workaround: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19647#issuecomment-480375386

Comment: @JamesJJ vfs also crashes with the graphdriver error. As the docs say, you can't switch storage driver on Mac Docker.

Comment: I see ... the `test builds` on the github page is meaning "testing building an image", not testing running builds of an image.....    An option would be to mount the affected paths as volumes e.g. bind mount to the host's disk, or mount as a tmpfs RAM disk. Using the example command from github page, adding a tmpfs resolves the `tar` error messages: `docker run -it --rm --mount "type=tmpfs,destination=/root"  heroku/cedar:14 /bin/bash -c "curl -sS https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh"`

Comment: @JamesJJ sadly doesn't work here; `tmpfs` doesn't support execution per https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35890. I get a 'Permission denied'.  (Docker 2.0.0.3). Both bind mount and volume result in the original error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by

- downgrading to https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18060-ce-mac70-2018-07-25 **(warning: wipes  all images)**
- in Preferences/Daemon/Advanced, typing

  {
    "storage-driver" : "aufs"
  }